# Teradata 15.1 SQL assistant: Ignore error and keep translating with hashing function

Tags: teradata

I'm trying to translate an `varchar` variable into a new variable with `hashing` function.

At some moment of processing it returns below error:

> ERROR 6706: The string contains an untranslatable character.

How to make it ignore such cases i.e. return `NULL` values and keep translating?

Comment: Which hashing function? Is it defined using LATIN and your input contains UNICODE?

Comment: Hello dnoeth. No special character set is defined for this function. Argument should just be varchar.

Comment: If no character set is defined when the function is created there's a default. Can you add the result of `SHOW FUNCTION myhashUDF`?